# method that store up to 100

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm a little unclear on how to correctly make this class.
The array I'm making can't find the symbol and I'm not sure how to correct this.

Error on compile is `ArrayList<Vehicle> db = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();` I think I just need to initialize it somewhere for it to work correctly.

Thank you for helping.

```
class Vehicle {  

   int capacity;
   String make;

   void setCapacity(int setCapacity) {
      this.capacity = setCapacity;
      System.out.println("New Capacity = " + setCapacity);
   }

   Vehicle(int theCapacity, String theMake) {
      capacity = theCapacity;
      make = theMake;
   }

   void print() {
      System.out.println("Vehicle Info:");
      System.out.println("  capacity = " + capacity + "cc" );
      System.out.println("  make = " + make );
   }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   public String type;
   public String model;

   public Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
      super(theCapacity, theMake);
      type = theType;
      model = theModel;
   }

   @Override
   public void print() {
      super.print();
      System.out.println("  type = " + type);
      System.out.println("  model = " + model);

   }

   @Override
   public void setCapacity(int setCapacity) {
      System.out.println("Cannot change capacity of a car");
   }
}
class VehicleDB {

   ArrayList<Vehicle> db = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(); 

   void addVehicle(Vehicle c){
      db.add(c);
   }

   void print(){
      System.out.println("=== Vehicle Data Base ===");
      for(Vehicle v: db){
         v.print();
      }
   }
}

class Task4 {
   public static void main (String[]args) {
      VehicleDB db = new VehicleDB () ;
      db.addVehicle (new Car (1200,"Holden","sedan","Barina"));
      db.addVehicle(new Vehicle(1500,"Mazda"));
      db.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you have to Add `import java.util.ArrayList;` at top of the file as @ Robby Cornelissen Said.

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Vehicle {
// your Code
}
```

After adding it works fine ad give the output :

```
=== Vehicle Data Base ===
Vehicle Info:
  capacity = 1200cc
  make = Holden
  type = sedan
  model = Barina
Vehicle Info:
  capacity = 1500cc
  make = Mazda
```